# JQuery sorting li by only first div inside

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, sorting

Try to make a sort

by using jquery sort. I would like to sort this li's by first div content(in my example, sort by aaa, bbb, ccc and ddd containing fields). Thanks in advance. Here is my code. Try to use .first() and changing the tags, it all useless( Hope for your help

**My code:**

```
function newSort(){
    $('#attachedCards ul li').html(
        $('#attachedCards ul li').children('div').sort(function (a, b) {
           return $(a).text().toUpperCase().localeCompare(
                $(b).text().toUpperCase());
        })
    );
}
```

**html-structure:**

```
<div id="attachedCards">
    <ul>
           <li>
                <div>ddd</div>
                <div>
                some useless info2
                </div>

            </li>

            <li>
            <div>ccc</div>
            <div>some useless info1</div>
            </li>
           <li>
           <div>bbb</div>
            <div>some useless info3</div>
           </li>
           <li>
            <div>aaa</div>
            <div>some useless info4</div>
           </li>
       </ul>
  </div>
```

**expected result:**

- aaa


      some useless info4
- bbb

      some useless info3
- ccc


      some useless info1
- ddd


      some useless info2

**I have now:**

```
  <ul>
    <li>
    aaa<br/>
    bbb<br/>
    ccc<br/>
    ddd<br/>
    some useless info1<br/>
    some useless info2<br/>
    some useless info3<br/>
    some useless info4<br/>
    </li>
    <li>
    aaa<br/>
    bbb<br/>
    ccc<br/>
    ddd<br/>
    some useless info1<br/>
    some useless info2<br/>
    some useless info3<br/>
    some useless info4<br/>
    </li>
    <li>
    aaa<br/>
    bbb<br/>
    ccc<br/>
    ddd<br/>
    some useless info1<br/>
    some useless info2<br/>
    some useless info3<br/>
    some useless info4<br/>
    </li>
    <li>
    aaa<br/>
    bbb<br/>
    ccc<br/>
    ddd<br/>
    some useless info1<br/>
    some useless info2<br/>
    some useless info3<br/>
    some useless info4<br/>
    </li>
    </ul>
```

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/1wocs4rn/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I made this. It works like i want

```
function newSort(){
$('#attachedCards ul').html(
    $('#attachedCards ul li').sort(function (a, b) {
        return $(a).children('div')[0].textContent.toUpperCase().localeCompare(
            $(b).children('div')[0].textContent.toUpperCase());  

    })
);
```

Thanks everyone for answering